# Why does the code repeat a stack insertion in an iterative function

Tags: python-3.x, iteration

My teacher put up a iterative code while learning about stack iteration. The code is to take the factorial of a number.

```
def facstack(nbr):
    from ast import literal_eval
    stk = ['F(%d)' % nbr]
    while stk != []:
        print('S =', stk)
        exp = stk.pop(0)
        nbr = literal_eval(exp[2:len(exp)-1])
        if nbr <= 1:
            result = 1
            while stk != []:
                exp = stk.pop(0)
                nbr = literal_eval(exp[2:len(exp)-1])
                result = result * nbr
        else:
            stk.insert(0, 'F(%d)' % nbr)
            stk.insert(0, 'F(%d)' % (nbr-1))
    return result
```

I understand everything about the code, except when we repeat the insertion of (nbr) before (nbr-1) in

```
stk.insert(0, 'F(%d)' % nbr)
stk.insert(0, 'F(%d)' % (nbr-1))
```

I tried to debug it to understand the values being passed but I still could not understand. Thank you.

Comment: what's `nbr`? I don't see it actually defined

Comment: This doesn't look like idiomatic Python at all. Inserting and popping from the left of the list instead of the right, incurring an additional O(N) performance penalty; inserting strings into the list and then using `literal_eval` to turn them back into numbers anyway; putting import statements inside functions; comparing lists to empty list literals to determine whether they're empty. Don't feel bad if the code looks strange to you, because it is.

Comment: @cat nbr is the number we want to compute the factorila of.

Comment: @Kevin I know it seems really weird but its the way he put it.